# What is the value of the variation stress energy tensor?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, metric-tensor, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

If we are living in a portion of space-time where the metric is very close to flat space and we know that the stress energy tensor is negligible at this portion of space-time is it ok to assume that $\frac{\delta T_{\mu\nu}}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}$ is also negligable?

Comment: I  don't see how $T$ even depends on the metric, so how could it's variation wrt. it be anything other than 0?

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/194889/2451

Comment: @0celo7 T does depend on the metric. It's related by the Field Equations. T is equal to G divided by k. I would suggest thinking through your comments a little more.

Comment: @Horus I responded to an earlier version of the question, which gave $T$ explicitly. No $g$.

Comment: @Horus Think of it this way. Suppose I have an equation $x^2=2$. The LHS has $x$ but that does not mean the RHS has to have any dependence on $x$.

Comment: @0celo7 That is certainly true but in this case its more like a $x^2 = y$ where both sides are variables. A change in the left will affect the right. Say now you specify y, then you will have an x for an answer. But change the value of y slightly and x will also have to change and vice versa. Besides the stress Energy tensor describes mass in a surrounding space described by the metric. Even a T in flat space depends on the Minkowski metric since it describes how the space curves and thereby changing values like density.

Answer (score 1):

No, not in general. Things are only negligible for certain purposes. For example, a field that obeys the Klein-Gordon equation [has the stress-energy tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein%E2%80%93Gordon_equation):$$T^{\mu\nu} = \frac{\hbar^2}{m} \left (g^{\mu \alpha} g^{\nu \beta} + g^{\mu \beta} g^{\nu \alpha} - g^{\mu\nu} g^{\alpha \beta} \right ) \partial_{\alpha}\bar\psi \partial_{\beta}\psi - g^{\mu\nu} m c^2 \bar\psi \psi$$
The derivative of this thing contains several important terms like $m c^2 \bar \psi \psi$ which are very important in certain contexts.